# jquery mobile plugin for encryption/decryption

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, encryption

I want to encrypt and decrypt the json object to be passed as URL parameters. is there a jquery mobile plugin which provides the encryption and decryption for this purpose as I found this link :

[http://www.jquery4u.com/security/10-jquery-security/](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/)

but this has all the outdated plugins.

If there is no option for me in jquery plugins, then I was planning to use this library.

http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

is this my best option as I want fast and lightweight library because of the URL parameters requirement or do I have a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [BASE64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

If you want some basic encryption that can be also decrypted then you should use plugin for **`BASE64`** encryption/decryption.

This plugin can be found as a part of **[jQuerySDK](http://www.jquerysdk.com/docs/Main_Page)** and if you want to find out more take a look at this [**link**](http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.toBASE64).

**Usage:**

```
$.toBASE64({
    foo: 'bar'
});

$.toBASE64(['foo', 'bar']);

$.toBASE64(12345);

$.toBASE64('Lorem ipsum');
```

### [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5), [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1), [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA)

**`MD5`** and **`SHA1`** are of course much much more secure then **`BASE64`**. Unfortunately they are used only for encoding. Instead of them you can use **`XTEA`**. It works on a same principle like **`BASE64`** but unlike **`BASE64`** you can use a key to encrypt/decrypt your string.

If you want to find out more go to this **[link](http://www.itsyndicate.ca/jquery/)**.

**Usage:**

```
//md5:
$().crypt({method:"md5",source:$("#phrase").val()});
//sha1:
$().crypt({method:"sha1",source:$("#phrase").val()});

//xtea
$().crypt({method:"xteab64enc",source:$("#phrase").val(),keyPass:$("#passPhrase").val()});
$().crypt({method:"xteab64dec",source:xteab64,keyPass:$("#passPhrase").val()});
```

### EDIT :

Regarding your first comment if you read my answer you would find tha BASE64 and XTEA are used to encrypt/decrypt your string. If you want to look past jQuery then there are only 2 relevant possibilities: Crypto-js and Stanford Crypto Library. They are best javascript can provide and difference is just like difference between Coke and Pepsi. At the end what will you use will depend on what are really going to encrypt/decrypt. For everything that is not passwords go with easy solutions like BASE64 or XTEA. For passwords go with Crypto-js orStanford Crypto Library.

Comment: thanks for your answer. for all the approaches the encrypt method is mentioned not the decrypt method. and I wanted your comments on the stanford library link that I shared in my question..

Comment: just wanted to know is there a way to generate cipher text of fixed length no matter how long the string is?

Comment: I have added more content to my answer. Take a look. Basically if you need to encrypt something important go with Stanford or Crypto-js in any other case use BASE64 or XTEA. Regarding your second question answer is yes but I don't think you can choose a length.