# Phonegap Facebook Local Storage omni-auth facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, cordova, local-storage

I have a question regarding the authentication process with mobile users. I am currently developing a mobile app with phonegap and jquery mobile.
I have setup a Ruby on Rails backend with the "omniauth-facebook" gem. Once the user logs in, I create a session and if he is a first time visitor I create a user model storing the necessary information.

Now I have a question regarding storing login details on Phonegap. People actually dont want to retype their email and password if they open a mobile app. Do the apps store email and password in the local storage? Or how is this done? Is this secure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are several storing solutions and you need to implement them by yourself.

First solution and probably the best one is a **[localstorage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)**. Used more often then other solutions. Implementation is easy and it works on any **`HTML5`** browser (or at least on every major **`HTML5`** browser). Only problem here is security but we will discuss it later.

Second solution is **`HTML5`** **`WebSQL`** mostly used on **`iOS`**. It has a better security but at the same time it requires more coding. Currently best solution to access **`WebSQL`** is **[persistance.js](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs)**.

Third solution is good old cookies but this is not that good solution mainly because it is such archaic technology. Not to mention it is no more secure then **`localStorage`** but unlike **`localstorage`** there's a good chance it will perish.

At the end we need to talk about security. **`Javascript`** provides you with more then enough security options. Probably best one is encryption/description of stored passwords. If you want to find out more take a look at my answer here: **[jquery mobile plugin for encryption/decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581621/jquery-mobile-plugin-for-encryption-decryption/16581915#16581915)**. MD5 or SHA1 are probably best solutions here for a password encryption, and your encryption key can be stored in your application, or even better on your server side, which will boost your security.